# can't build .net core API image in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am trying to build image for .net core 3.1 web api project but unable to build image
i get stuck at restoring project packages via dotnet restore
i get stuck at when i use dotnet build command ( does not find the solution or project file)

Directory Structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7sMq.png

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as base
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app

#copy all project and solution files
COPY ./SSFS.Service/.csproj ./SSFS.Service/
COPY ./SSF.EDM/.csproj ./SSF.EDM/
COPY ./API/.csproj ./API/
COPY ./.sln ./

WORKDIR /app/API
RUN dotnet restore "SSFAPI.csproj"
#copy rest of files
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app

#build the project to restore packages
RUN dotnet build --source "./SSFAPI.sln" -c Release -o /publish

#public the project to a folder
RUN dotnet publish --source "SSFAPI.sln" -c Release -o /publish

FROM base AS final
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SSFAPI.dll"]
```

> output of above is as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqoKv.png

> If i build the project using dotnet command then out is as shown below
>   Output is as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9bV5.png

Answer (score -1):

The Dockerfile is set up to be run from the solution root. You're probably running `docker build` from the project directory (i.e. where the Dockerfile actually is).

Comment: even if i run from root directory it still searching sln file from SSF.Service folder  ie c:\app\SSF.Service\SSFAPI.sln

Comment: so what is the correct way of running this dockerfile then?